# How do I remove Kubuntu loading screen?

Tags: kubuntu

I want to have the normal boot instructions and not the loading Kubuntu screen.
How do I remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit `/etc/default/grub` and find the line that looks like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

and remove the `quiet splash` parameters, which may leave the line looking like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

After editing, run `sudo update-grub`
and you should boot without the Kubuntu loading screen